# error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement c#

Tags: c#

thank you in advance and please note im fairly new to c#,

Im trying to do the below test for kata on codewars but im getting the error in the title and i dont undrestand why ? i used the same code on visualStudio and it works fine

Test :
If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Finish the solution so that it returns the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below the number passed in.

Note: If the number is a multiple of both 3 and 5, only count it once

code :

```
    public static int Solution(int value)
  {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i= 1; i < value; i++)
            {
                int multiples3 = 3 * i;
                int multiples5 = 5 * i;
                if (multiples3 != multiples5)
                {
                    sum = sum+multiples3+multiples5;
                }
                else
                {
                    sum = sum + multiples3;
                }     
            }
    return (sum);
  }
```

Comment: There's no error in the code you posted: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VpreG7

Comment: what line was the error on. We have the error, but we don't have the line. BTW, this is what CS0201 means: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0201

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but this code won't solve the problem in any way. You could use a `HashSet<int>` for storage and two `while` loops to add values to it (to avoid `if` conditions).

Comment: Logically the line " if (multiples3 != multiples5)" will never be true. Also "return sum;" is enough -no need for "(" ,  ")" .

Comment: @VytautasPlečkaitis actualy the line " if (multiples3 != multiples5)" always true it purpose so that when there is the multuples  of 3 and 5 is the same so it will add just one to the usm as for the retrun i just added to just check

Comment: Hi @Jimi as i said im new to the c# and dev and im using codewars to train and i dont know the hashset<int> i will look for it and learn it

Comment: Hi All, 

i think codewards editer was bugged or seomthing because it worked again and i didn"t change any thing but anyway my solution was wrong for the given task, 

i really dont understand what's wrong can some one help me ? ( the task is below ) 
""" : If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Finish the solution so that it returns the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below the number passed in. """

Comment: @OUSSAMABEYGAHAR "int multiples3 = 3 * i; int multiples5 = 5 * i; " if i is not 0 then 5*i will never be equal 3*i.

Answer (score 1):

CS0201 is caused by line

> return (sum);

Change it to

> return sum;

Simplified solution would be:

```
 public static int Solution(int value)
  {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i= 1; i < value; i++)
            {
                bool multiples3 = i % 3 == 0;
                bool multiples5 = i % 5 == 0;
                if (multiples3 || multiples5)
                {
                   sum += i;
                }     
            }
    return sum;
  }
```

If we take in account that earliest i that matches condition is 3, then it can be simplified even more :

```
 public static int Solution(int value)
  {
            if (value < 3) return 0; // prevent value being less than 3, e.g. -1

            int sum = 0;
            for (int i= 3; i < value; i++)
            {
                if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
                {
                   sum += i;
                }     
            }
    return sum;
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Vytautas, thank you very much for your help your solution is perfect , thank you, even so i m still trying to undertand it, i will not use it to  answer the task i will try to find my way otherwise there is point in learning :) but im stilll far away so far away

Comment: @OUSSAMABEYGAHAR I'll give you a hint - in general this test is very similar to fizz-buzz. You will just need to adapt it.